# EditText via Java

Tags: java, android

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma view personalizada e gostaria de saber como seria possível adicionar um EditText via Java(sem uso de xml, e sem fazer referencia a classe R pois seria via código java, se possível). Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia, Michael!

Você pode criar `Views` de forma programática (usando o Java). Por exemplo

```
EditText etUserName = new EditText(getContext());
```

Como você está criando uma `View` personalizada, passe o contexto para o construtor da `View` por meio do método `getContext()`. Se você criou sua `View` na própria `Activity`, é só passar o próprio contexto

```
EditText etUserName = new EditText(this);
```

Não esqueça que você precisará criar um `layout` pai e então adicionar seu `EditText`

```
LinearLayout mLayout = /* Obtenha o layout */;
EditText etUserName = new EditText(context)
etUserName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

myLayout.addView(etUserName);
```

Ou se tratando de uma `View` personalizada, dê um `extends` numa `View` de `layout` e crie o `EditText` como dito acima

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        EditText etUserName = new EditText(context)
        addView(etUserName);
    }
}
```

Porém, eu aconselharia criar sua `UI` de forma declarativa, por meio do `xml`, pois terá menos trabalho. Espero que isso ajude!